# Another solution to this Java RandomCount program?

Tags: java, arrays

```
 public class SimpleRandomCount extends RandomCount
{
/**
 * Generate an array containing elements in a random order
 * 
 * @param size the size of the array to be generated
 */
public SimpleRandomCount(int size) {
    super(size);
}

/**
 * Randomise the array
 */
protected void randomise() {
    int[] copy = new int[array().length];
    int randomIndex;

    // used to indicate if elements have been used
    boolean[] used = new boolean[array().length];
    Arrays.fill(used,false);
    for (int index = 0; index < array().length; index++) {
        do {
            randomIndex = randomIndex();
        } while (used[randomIndex]);

        copy[index] = array()[randomIndex];
        used[randomIndex] = true;
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < array().length; index++) {
        array()[index] = copy[index];
    }
   }
  public static void main(String [] args){
  RandomCount count = new SimpleRandomCount(5);
  System.out.println("Array is " + Arrays.toString(count.array()));
  }
 }
```

The SimpleRandomCount class is part of another class called RandomCount. I was wondering if there was a cleverer, shorter way of randomising the numbers without using a boolean value to help do it?

Thanks for any help it is very much appreciated.

Comment: Belongs at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need it to be particularly efficient, you can rely on `Collections.shuffle` to do the work.

You would need to convert the array to a `List` and then copy the elements back:

```
    // copy the array to a list
    List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int index = 0; index < array().length; index++)
    {
        copy.add(array()[index]);
    }

    // Shuffle the elements in the copy
    Collections.shuffle(copy);

    // copy them back to the array
    for (int index = 0; index < array().length; index++) {
        array()[index] = copy.get(index);
    }
```